# creating new Instance of scala object in java

Tags: java, class, scala, reflection, scala-java-interop

I'm trying to create a system that will load a class extending Mod when it is written in scala OR java. I have the class object and I check if the class is written in scala by checking if the class has the @ScalaMod annotation. And I handle the different language by a Language adapter I wrote. But I keep getting this error.

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.6.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) ~[?:1.6.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) ~[?:1.6.0_65]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) ~[?:1.6.0_65]
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:134) [launchwrapper-1.9.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28) [launchwrapper-1.9.jar:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.6.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) ~[?:1.6.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) ~[?:1.6.0_65]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) ~[?:1.6.0_65]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120) [idea_rt.jar:?]
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[?:1.6.0_65]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:249) ~[?:1.6.0_65]
    at net.acomputerdog.BlazeLoader.mod.language.IModLanguage$ScalaModLanguage.newInstance(IModLanguage.java:10) ~[IModLanguage$ScalaModLanguage.class:?]
    at net.acomputerdog.BlazeLoader.mod.ModList.load(ModList.java:62) ~[ModList.class:?]
    at net.acomputerdog.BlazeLoader.main.BlazeLoader.init(BlazeLoader.java:96) ~[BlazeLoader.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run(Minecraft.java:781) ~[Minecraft.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:94) ~[Main.class:?]
    ... 11 more
```

this is the Language Adapter class:

```
public interface IModLanguage {
public Mod newInstance(Class<?> objectClass) throws Exception;

public static class ScalaModLanguage implements IModLanguage {
    public Mod newInstance(Class<?> objectClass) throws Exception{
        Class<?> scalaObject = Class.forName(objectClass.getName(), true, ScalaModLanguage.class.getClassLoader());
        return (Mod) scalaObject.getField("MODULE$").get(null);
    }
}

public static class JavaModLanguage implements IModLanguage {
    public Mod newInstance(Class<?> objectClass) throws Exception {
        return (Mod) objectClass.newInstance();
    }
}
```

this is the scala Mod class:

```
    @ScalaMod
    object XplosionCoreBL extends Mod
{
    val xplosionModHandler: XplosionModHandler = new XplosionModHandler
    var newModVersions: ListBuffer[NewModVersionEntry] = new ListBuffer[NewModVersionEntry]()
    val xplosionConfig: ConfigHandler = new ConfigHandler(new File(ApiGeneral.configDir, "XplosionCore-BL.cfg"), this, "Everything deleted from this file will restore itself with its default value.")
    val logger: XplosionLogger = new XplosionLogger("XplosionCore-BL")

    override def getModId: String = "XplosionCore-BL"

    override def getModName: String = "XplosionCore-BL"
    override def getIntModVersion: Int = 0

    override def getStringModVersion: String = "1.0.0"

    override def isCompatibleWithBLVersion: Boolean = true

    override def getModDescription: String = "Core for all XplosionMods made with BlazeLoader."

    override def load
    {
        VersionCheckHandler.checkXplosionModsVersions();

        xplosionConfig.load();
    }

    override def start
    {
    }

    override def eventPlayerLogin(player: EntityPlayerMP)
    {
        EventHandler.onPlayerLogin(player)
    }
```

And here is the handeling code:

```
Class<? extends Mod> cls = iterator.next();
        Mod mod = null;
        try {
            mod = getModLanguage(cls).newInstance(cls);
```

.

```
public static IModLanguage getModLanguage(Class<?> modClass) throws Exception {
    if (modClass.isAnnotationPresent(ScalaMod.class)) {
        return new IModLanguage.ScalaModLanguage();
    }
    else {
        return new IModLanguage.JavaModLanguage();
    }
}
```

Comment: I noticed so far, that Java Reflection cannot instantiate Scala `object`